# Error: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I'm trying to build a style transfer model these are the functions I used

```
def style_transfer(model, style_path, content_path, learning_rate,style_weight, content_weight, epochs):
    
    history = {"content_loss":[], "style_loss":[], "total_loss":[]}
    style_image = img_preprocess(style_path)
    content_image = img_preprocess(content_path)
    
    # getting content and style features
    style_features = get_features(model, style_image)["style"] 
    content_features = get_features(model, content_image)["content"]
    
    # adding some noise to the content_image
    content_img_shape = tf.shape(content_image)
    noise = tf.random.uniform(content_img_shape, minval=0, maxval=0.5)
    gen_image = tf.add(content_image, noise)
    gen_image = tf.Variable(gen_image, tf.float32)
    # changing the gen_image
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate, beta_1=0.99, epsilon=1e-8)
    for i in range(epochs):
        all_losses = gradient_descent(model,
                                      opt,
                                      gen_image,
                                      style_features,
                                      content_features,
                                      style_weight,
                                      content_weight)
        
        history["total_loss"].append(all_losses[0].numpy())
        history["style_loss"].append(all_losses[1].numpy())
        history["content_loss"].append(all_losses[2].numpy())
        
        if i % 100 == 0:
            img = PIL.Image.fromarray(deprocess_img(gen_image.numpy()))
            display.clear_output(wait=True)
            display.display_png(img)
            print(f"epoch: {i}\ntotal_loss: {all_losses[0]}")
            
    return history
```

and also the grandient descent function

```
@tf.function()
def gradient_descent(model,optimizer, gen_image, style_features,
                     content_features, style_weight, content_weight):

    with tf.GradientTape() as g:
      g.watch(gen_image)
      gen_image_sfeatures , gen_image_cfeatures = get_features(model, gen_image).values()
      j_content = content_loss(content_features , gen_image_cfeatures)
      j_style = style_loss(style_features , gen_image_sfeatures)
      j_total = total_loss(j_style , j_content, style_weight, content_weight)
    
    norm_means = np.array([103.939, 116.779, 123.68])
    min_vals = -norm_means
    max_vals = 255 - norm_means
    grad = g.gradient(j_total , gen_image)
    optimizer.apply_gradients([(grad, gen_image)])
    gen_image.assign(clip(gen_image, min_vals, max_vals))
    return j_total, j_style, j_content
```

when executing the program for the first time. it runs without issues. But when I try to execute the style_transfer function for the second time i get the error below, and to make it works again i should re-execute the gradient descent function. so whenever i run style transfer function i should run gradient descent before.

```
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py:512, in _BaseOptimizer.add_variable_from_reference(self, model_variable, variable_name, shape, initial_value)
    510     else:
    511         initial_value = tf.zeros(shape, dtype=model_variable.dtype)
    512 variable = tf.Variable(
    513     initial_value=initial_value,
    514     name=f"{variable_name}/{model_variable._shared_name}",
    515     dtype=model_variable.dtype,
    516     trainable=False,
    517 )
    518 self._variables.append(variable)
    519 return variable

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/tmp/ipykernel_29/1467961479.py", line 16, in gradient_descent  *
        optimizer.apply_gradients([(grad, gen_image)])
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 1174, in apply_gradients  **
        return super().apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, name=name)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 637, in apply_gradients
        self.build(trainable_variables)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/adam.py", line 139, in build
        self.add_variable_from_reference(
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 1106, in add_variable_from_reference
        return super().add_variable_from_reference(
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/optimizers/optimizer.py", line 512, in add_variable_from_reference
        variable = tf.Variable(

    ValueError: tf.function only supports singleton tf.Variables created on the first call. Make sure the tf.Variable is only created once or created outside tf.function. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#creating_tfvariables for more information.
```

but the problem is I used `tf.Variable` once and outside `tf.function`, could you help me please to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be with the Adam optimizer. This optimizer records momentum for each `Variable`, and to do that it creates new `Variable`s associated with each `Variable` to be optimized (i.e. watched by gradient tape). Those new `Variable`s associated with `gen_image` are causing trouble with `tf.function`.

Perhaps the most straightforward solution would be to **remove the `tf.function` decorator** and see how much slow-down there is. Eventually, it might be more canonical to wrap the optimization loop inside a `keras.Model` and associate the optimizer by `model.compile(optimizer=opt)`. Then it would be easier to isolate the optimization on different images by creating different instances of the `Model`.